# How to solve different of timeout time in microservices?

Tags: java, rest, timeout, microservices

I have two microservices that each of them service to each others by rest web services.
 
My problem is difference of timeout time of them.
You assume that micro B calls an API of micro A and timeout of B is less than A.According to synchronizing way,B is waiting until A response to.
Time of proccessing of A is more than timeout time of B then B is lossed connection from A.From the perspective of A, everything is ok 
but there is any result to B.
How Does B solve his problem or another word how does B get the related result of calling method of A.
I sovle this problem with my own way but I want to know if there are any standard way or any design pattern for this problem.

Comment: by increasing the timeout

Comment: Increasing timeout has overhead for my application I can not

Comment: you cannot then

Comment: As your comment shows, There are any solution in microservices world?I think that It is not impossible

Comment: it's not impossible, but there is no silver bullet. One possibility is to let A return a request ID immediately, and provide a way to check the status of the processing of the request, and get the result when it's available.

Comment: Would you give  a link or document to study in depth?

Comment: I thins that It is impossible for asynchrozing way?Is It?

Comment: That is a way to make the requests asynchronous when the timeout for an http request cannot be increased.

Comment: But of course, if the technology you're using allow asynchronous requests, that's the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helping,Would you give me a link to study in depth?

Comment: try this: https://netty.io/

Comment: My application is integrated with spring framework.Does spring have as same as  this mechanism?

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets